# How to deal with duplicate photos syncing on two different devices?

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, photos.app

I imported photos from my iPhone to macOS photos using cable. now macOS is uploading photos to iCloud, my iPhone is uploading photos as well but I paused it. So basically the two devices are trying to upload the same photos to iCloud, one of them is paused and the other is running.

Will the iCloud have duplicate photos? How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 15 and lower iCloud tries to sort out duplicates when you import but your case probably won’t be caught since it’s syncing that’s injecting  duplicates. Even with you trying to export, delete and import, you might need a tool that specializes in that detection and cleaning.

I am a super happy customer of fat cat software.

- https://fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/

The new iOS 16 duplicate finding looks very promising. It’s not as full featured as Power Photos, but it does work on the iPhone directly. Initial results are quite promising, but I haven’t tested it extensively yet.

[image: iOS 16 duplicate photo merge interface on iPhone]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 16 and (future macOS Ventura), a duplicates album will appear that can merge your duplicates.

In macOS Ventura (and likely in iOS 16), you can scroll through and verify everything it's identified, then select all the photos and merge them at once.